# Show spinner (react-native-loading-spinner-overlay) between navigations

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I know this is a broad question, but I'm having trouble grasping the correct way of things in react-native.

What follows are a couple of assumptions I made while learning react-native
My app is built around a `StackNavigator` hooked up to redux.
The first screen in the navigator is my login screen. So this is basically the 'main' screen that will always be loaded. The users logs in (or is already logged in) and is forwarded to another page. On dispatching a navigation I can update the state of the login page. I want to use this logic to display the spinner until the navigation is complete.

The problem is, when the user chooses to login by scanning a QR code, a new screen opens which loads a camera view. This takes a couple of milliseconds/seconds. I'm trying to find a way to show a loading animation using [react-native-loading-spinner-overlay](https://js.coach/react-native/react-native-loading-spinner-overlay?category=indicators&filters=ios&sort=new&page=2).

```
export class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            spinnerVisible: false,
        };
    }

    render() {
        return <KeyboardAvoidingView
            style={styles.container}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainerStyle}
            behavior="position"
        >
            <Spinner visible={this.state.spinnerVisible} />
            <Image
                source={images.app.title}
                style={styles.titleImage}
            />
            <View style={styles.columnForm}>
                <Button
                    title="INLOGGEN MET QR CODE"
                    wrapperBorderStyle={styles.titleButton}
                    onPress={this.onScanQRCode.bind(this)}
                    // disabled={true}
                />
                <View style={{flex:0, flexDirection: 'row', marginTop:10, marginBottom:10}}>
                // removed other elements
                <Button
                    title="INLOGGEN"
                    wrapperBorderStyle={styles.titleButton}
                    onPress={() => alert('de nest werkt')} />
            </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    }

    onScanQRCode() {
        // UPDATE STATE HERE TO SHOW SPINNER?
        this.setState({spinnerVisible: true});
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Camera' }));
    }
}
```

This works, but the spinners is shown when the camera view is rendered instead of it being shown when the user presses the button.
Furthermore, I don't know how to hide the spinner when the camera view is rendered other than with a `setTimeout` to change the state after a predefined amount of time. That approach would feel "hacky".

What would be the correct way to achieve this scenario?
I have access to the dispatch, navigation, and routes through `this.props`.

Answer (score 2):

Back again, and definitely more confident than last time I asked this question.

I solved the issue by realizing the code itself is executed synchronously.
Because `this.setState` is asynchronous, the screen will not refresh before you actually navigate away and no visual hint is given.

Best thing to do is wrap your navigation code in a timeout so that `this.setState` actually sets the state and refreshes the screen to show an indicating spinner.

```
onScanQRCode() {
    this.setState({spinnerVisible: true});
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Camera' }));
    }, 100);
}
```